# How do I properly reinstall a Go project

Tags: go

I have a Go project I installed on my machine via `glide install` and `go install`. I need to reinstall this go project. What's the best way about doing this? Can I just delete the folder that contains the go project? Do I need to consider anything else in order to achieve a clean reinstall?

Comment: What do you mean by "install"? Installing usually means installing the compilation artifacts and/or resulting binary, so "re-installing" would just be running `go install` again. Replacing the source with an older version is just that, revert the source code; either through the vcs or by fetching it again.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for the clarification. I'm still learning the intricacies of Go.

By "install" I mean rebuilding the project from scratch. Some files were generated by this project and I'm hoping a reinstall would rebuild the files.

Comment: If some files were generated, you need to run whatever generated those files. That's not a standard part of installation, so it's up to the particular project you're working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
cd ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/<project-name>; go clean
rm -f ${GOPATH}/bin/<your-project-executable>
# If your project is hosted on github
rm -rf ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/<project-name>

go get github.com/<project-name>
cd ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/<project-name>
glide install
go install
```

Comment: Thanks Rico. I'll check this out.

Comment: This may not trigger a full rebuild as it does not remove the compiled package files. See e.g. [`go clean`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remove_object_files)

Comment: Is this answer still relevant in 2021? (no $GOHOME set)

Comment: You can do a `go clean` before running `go install`